# Replacing Tuxedo calls with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, transactions, service-layer, tuxedo

I have been tasked with replacing some Tuxedo services with the equivalent JDBC calls.

Considering a single Tuxedo service, I have started by creating a JDBC DAO, which implements the same interface as the existing Tuxedo DAO. I am calling methods on this from a new Service layer. I am planning to use the Spring @Transactional annotation on my Service layer to handle JDBC transactions.

Tuxedo handles transactions internally, hence a single Tuxedo DAO method call is comparable to multiple method calls on a JDBC DAO, which would be called from the new Service layer.

Given the above it makes sense to me that the Tuxedo DAO should really be a service level entity. Does that make sense?

Any thoughts on the best way to lay this out from a Service/DAO layer perspective would be appreciated. I need to keep the Tuxedo DAO for legacy purposes, but refactoring this into the Service layer should not be an issue if required.

Thanks
Jay

Comment: My point above being, Tuxedo is providing data-access, hence it could be a _DAO_. However, since it also handles transactions it might be better placed as a _Service_.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

It makes a lot of sense. In fact, a Tuxedo Service (depending if it's only a DB access or if it has some more business logic) could be replaced by a simple DB-DAO or by some sort of service (EJB, WebService, etc. depending on the standard technologies used in the enterprise).

I would try starting by classifying the services so you can decide what to do with each one of them and maybe fix some strategies. Something like "DB-DAO", "OTHER-DATASTORE-DAO", "MORE COMPLEX SERVICE".

After you did this work, you can build your direct DAO's and services. If you decide to deploy the services on a different infrastructure (scaling issues or just because many applications will use them and you want to keep a clean visibility), you can still write DAOs to consume them and respect the original calling interface, but with a new implementation behind.

Regards